# Java socket connection hangs 60 seconds before reading last line

Tags: java, sockets

I have developed manually a soap connection via Java sockets (it was a very simple soap request and Axis was giving lots of build problem).

To achieve this, I basically copied the HTTP header I was getting out of Soap UI when , and coded the follwing:

```
String hostname = "aaaaa";
int port = 11111;
InetAddress  addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);
sock.setSoTimeout(100000);
BufferedWriter  wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
wr.write("POST " + "http://aaaa:11111/servicePath" + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
wr.write("Host: aaaaa:11111\r\n");
wr.write("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n");
wr.write("Content-Length: " + soapXml.length() + "\r\n");
wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n");
//wr.write("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
wr.write("SOAPAction: \"/someSoapAction\"\r\n");
wr.write("User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)\r\n");
wr.write("\r\n");
wr.write(soapXml);
wr.flush();
```

The requests are successful, meaning I get from the service the responses I expect. 
For instance, when I put in my hand written "soapXml" some invalid parameters, I get a 500 error back with XML explaining the problem, If I set everything correctly I get a 200 OK with an xml body following the header.

**The problem is that the socket hangs 60 seconds before reading the HTTP body in case of a 200OK.**

It basically reads the full header, then waits 60 seconds, then (I think some protocol times out and) finally reads the xml body.

Here's the code with which I read the response:

```
String line;
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            i++;
            LOG.debug("cycle: "+i+" -------- "+line);
                     //after printing the header, it hangs 60 seconds before printing the follwing XML  
            if ((line.length() >0) && (line.charAt(0) == '<'))
            {
                responseXML = line;
            }
}
```

Here is a sample 200 OK header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1052
Date: Sun, 13 Jan 2013 08:33:45 GMT -- hanging 60 seconds here
-- blank line
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>................</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Has anybody ever faced this? Please note this is not a server problem apparently, since with soap UI the answer is immediately provided.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server environment change (a new machine was provided) solved the issue.

Now response time is below 1 sec also for 200OK.

Unluckily I don't have any details regarding the tech stack of the envrionment. Anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The server is keeping the connection open for HTTP keep-alive, clearly for a 60 second timeout. Either change to HTTP 1.0 or else take note of the returned Content-length header and stop reading at that many bytes.

Comment: Thanks EJP, I changed the request putting HTTP 1.0 instead of 1.1 but the server replies with 1.1 and I have the same hanging issue.  The Content lenght may be an option but it's not very safe since it may vary (there are transaction ids in the responses). I would like to know if there is any safer way.

Comment: @Tia Using the Content-length is not an 'option', it is the *required* way to find the end of the body as defined by the HTTP 1.1 protocol. And *of course* it varies, that's why it's sent. I cannot understand this remark. You don't need a safer way. This is the way, and there is nothing unsafe about it. Your Web browser is using it at this instant.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself, the problem is that my application hangs **before** reading the last line (which nothing else than the xml body), not after, so I'm not sure how I should use the content lenght.. They are moving the server to another environment for other reasons, I hope this will help.

Comment: @Tia If that's true it must take 60 seconds for the server to send the body after the head. Nothing you can do about that at the client end. NB Why aren't you using HttpURLConnection for this task?

Comment: @EJB the thing is that it used to take so long only via java socket connection, not with soap UI.

Comment: Hi, the server environment change (a new machine was provided) solved the issue. Now response time is below 1 sec also for 200OK. Unluckily I don't have any details regarding the tech stack of the envrionment. Anyways thanks for help.